# All possible cycles passing through a vertex "v" containing a particular label

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal

For any directed/undirected labelled graph `G := (V,E,L)`, where L is the finite set of labels, and every edge has a label. For simplicity, let us assume that `L = {a,b}`. Is there a P-time algorithm to determine whether all possible cycles passing through a vertex "v" has at least one edge (every cycle) with label "a"? We can assume that G is simple with self-loops.

The naive approach would be to enumerate all possible cycles passing through "v" and then check every edge label. I was thinking of a more efficient approach, to eliminate traversing some repeated paths based on whether "a" was encountered/not, and reduce the complexity to that of DFS - I cannot decisively conclude for now that this will be P-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is equivalent to asking whether there exists a cycle that goes through $v$ and uses only b-edges.  This can be tested by deleting all a-edges, then testing whether the resulting graph has a cycle that goes through $v$ using any standard algorithm.  This gives an algorithm that runs in polynomial time -- in fact, in linear time.